# ready function not being called on safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Why is that ready is not called  on safari ,it is being called on firefox,Intrnet explorer,chrome.
More info :Jquery.js in included in the parent page and that is the reason is not included in my page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
hasflash = detectFlash();


   alert('1');

  $("#status").css({'display':'none'});
  getresource('1','1');
  $(".step[step=1]").css({'background':'#FFF58F'});
  $("#img1,#img2,#img3,#img4,#img5,#img6,#img7,#img8").hide();

 });
```

Comment: maybe a runtime error in detectFlash() only in safari that keeps the alert from running so you only think the ready function isn't being called? Hard to say with such limited info.

Comment: If i remove all the code and say alert('1'); Its still the same issue.

Comment: Still more info is needed. Where is the page coming from, a server, local file system, is it html, php, asp, what?

Comment: You know that Safari is only used by 4% of the web population, just keep that in mind when you allocate your time for such problems.

Comment: Could you include the HTML or a link to it - it is possibly to do with where you have put the javascript include tag.

Answer (score 0):

> Jquery.js in included in the parent page and that is the reason is not included in my page

If your page is running inside of a frame or iframe, you will also need to reference the jquery library on your page as you won't inherit it from the parent page.